# Using Jenkins over a NAS

Tags: jenkins

I am planning on setting up a new Jenkins server at our company. I want to keep all deployable artifacts in Jenkins for a wide variety of reason (easy access, access control, etc.).

The company would prefer if these deployable artifacts were kept on a NAS. That's fine with me. I can set Jenkins up to use the NAS and simply keep the entire configuration there. My concern is that some projects might build slower since it's a remote drive over a network connection. I figure I can configure problematic jobs to use a local working directory to speed things up as required.

However, it would be nice if there was an easy way to setup Jenkins so that the working directory is automatically on the local machine while everything else could be on the NAS. That would require less setup and work on my part. I don't have to remember to setup a local working directory when required, and I don't have to track which jobs have a funky working directory.

I see two ways this could be done:

- Setup Jenkins so that the working directory is calculated to be a particular local directory. For exmaple, if the job is on `/mnt/nas/jenkins/jobs/foo`, the working directory would be `/opt/jenkins/jobs/foo` or `/opt/local/jenkins/foo`.
- Somehow configure the whole system so that certain directories are local while others are on the NAS. For example all directories under `/opt/local/jenkins/jobs/foo` are on the NAS except for `/opt/local/jenkins/jobs/foo/workdir` is local storage.

Is there a way to configure Jenkins to automatically use a different directory as a working directory instead of `workdir` under the job directory? Or is there a way to configure the environment to do this?

Comment: Another alternative is to publish your release artifacts to a dedicated repository, like Nexus. My preference to keep Jenkins as stateless as possible and use my repo as the release record. That approach means I'm less tied to a particular build technology and more immune to data loss

Comment: We are using Artifactory, and we'll certainly put the jars/wars we create in Artifactory, so other projects will use them via Maven or Ivy. However, there's a great advantage of keeping artifacts that you tend to deploy in production (think zips, rpms, and ears) in Jenkins. It ties these deployments into development. For example, "We're deploying foo.rpm into production. Did Bob make the change?" "Yes, it was made in Build #20, and we're deploying Build #21." Keeping artifacts in Jenkins gives us a language in talking about various releases. Build #22 is not stable. QA is testing Build #40.

Comment: That's true. You can also do this using the staging suite in Nexus. As I stated above, my preference is to have a single system of record.

Comment: Interesting idea using the _staging suite_. Artifactory has a similar integration to Jenkins where deployed artifacts keep their build tracked. I'll have to play around with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did this at my day job by using symlinks for certain subdirectories under $JENKINS_HOME.  In our case, we wanted to store all of the job configurations, history and published artifacts on a SAN volume and leave the rest of the Jenkins files on local storage.  This was just a matter of creating a symlink from $JENKINS_HOME/jobs to a directory on the SAN volume.

In your case, it looks like you would want to set $JENKINS_HOME to point to a directory on your NAS, but have the workspace directories for your builds reside on local storage.  This is also straightforward since the workspaces for each build are kept in a subdirectory; I *think* this is $JENKINS_HOME/workspace, sorry I can't confirm since our setup uses separate build slaves and doesn't have any executors set up on the master.

One word of warning with using NAS; we used NAS for Jenkins before switching to SAN, and found that we would regularly get errors saving changes to job configurations due to Jenkins being unable to delete temporary files created by the snapshotting feature on the NAS.  The problem went away when we turned off snapshots.

Comment: I've recently discovered that Jenkins has implemented two new configuration options in the global configurations. You can now specify that the working directory be placed elsewhere **or** specify where the builds directory (the record of all the builds) be placed. Either of these options would do exactly what I want. I used Jenkins at my last job, and updated Jenkins just back in April and those options weren't there, so they're fairly recent. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

I've been informed of two ways of doing this:

- Setup a slave, and a slave can be on the same machine as the Jenkins server, and have the slave do all the builds. The slave would build locally, and then ship the information back to the Jenkins server which would be on the NAS. The working directory is local since it's the slave that's doing the build, but the artifacts would be on the NAS since that's where Jenkins would store them.
- Jenkins has two new options in its general configuration. I missed them on the first glance. They're on the very top of the configuration screen, and you have to press the *Advanced* button to see them. One allows you to specify where you want the working directory, so it's sits outside of `$JENKINS_HOME`. I could setup `$JENKINS_HOME` on the NAS, then tell Jenkins to put the local directories on the local drive. The other allows me to specify where to put the build records. I could keep the build records on the NAS (including the archived artifacts), and setup `JENKINS_HOME` on the local machine.

This is exactly what I was looking for. Apparently, other people needed the same thing.